# how to make an array of UITableView @property's at build-time

Tags: ios, uitableview

How can I control the number of multiple UITableView's at build-time, using a single #define number?

My app presently needs 4 UITableView's.  Later, the number will increase, so I want to control this at build-time with a single #define of how many.

But I get an error when I use an array in the @property declaration:

```
#define TOTAL_TX_CHANNELS  4

@interface blah() <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate CBPeripheralDelegate>
{
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView* channel_tableView[ TOTAL_TX_CHANNELS ] ;
```

What's the trick?  Should I use an NSArray or something?

Comment: Why would you need four table views if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: This app will show the system status map of a local network of several iOS devices and embedded computers.  The four TABLEVIEW's will show 4 columns, each column will display all the computers on a communication channel -- 4 communication channels, which will increase in the future as the product evolves.

Comment: Do I even need the property for the UITableView?  The 4 tableViews will be created programatically at run-time.  Perhaps I can create an array of UITableView* in the implementation.  Isn't the property only needed for wiring up the nib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was not to use an a property array, but to use an UITextView array at implementation scope, the .m...

UITextView*     channel_pipe_textview[ TOTAL_TX_CHANNELS ];

Then, in function viewDidLayoutSubviews I created a UITableView for each channel, and added the standard functions for initializing the cells, all by following Apple's excellent UITableView programming guide.

It worked perfectly, completely independent of storyboard:  I get four vertical side-by-side columns displaying any kind of images and text details regarding every device on the channel, with the ability to scroll, which allows any number of devices per channel.

The Apple UITableView Programming Guide also has tutorial and sample code for programmatically generating UITableViews solely at run-time.

Comment: I just demonstrated the app to my client, based on this solution, and the angel and CEO loved it.  The UITableViews let me easily fill the screen with repeating patterns representing system components, which they understood AT-A-GLANCE (my intent) and they got so excited they started brainstorming, I took lots of notes, and I was told to proceed with project.  (I love software.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `NSArray`.

If it's configured in Interface Builder you could use:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection (UITableView) NSArray * tableViews;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly do you need to control the # of UITableViews? 
If you must do this, you could do some mathematical operation.

```
int adder = 4;
int currentNumberOfTvs = 4;

//Do some logic, that will add the number of current table views

if (...) //Test if user has added, or however, if another table view was added, 
{
 adder++;//now adder = 5. So you have a current count of how many table views there are
}
```

Hope that helps:)

Comment: Need to control the number because the number might change depending on product requirements and customer usage.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others that this is a terrible implementation. Wain's answer is very good.

However, still it is possible to implement it this way, just make sure to declare the property as

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) UITableView** channel_tableView;
```

Reference counting works only on Obj-C objects but you are creating a C array here.

Note that you have to use `malloc` to allocate the storage.

If you don't want to `malloc`, implement it as an ivar:

```
@interface Blah {
    UITableView* channel_tableView[4];
}
@end
```